# Django object not filling form in UpdateView

Tags: django, templates, object

For some reason my object in this one particular view isn't making it into the form in my template.

In the template I can do `{{ object }}` and get the expected results, but the form is empty. The form snippet is pretty bland. I haven't broken anything out for styling yet.  Same with the view.  I have a much larger one that checks for permissions etc, but they have the same end result:  object makes it to the template, but never populates the form.

Just for the record, I have done stuff like `form.first_name.value`, but I get `None` back.  Any thoughts why an UpdateView wouldn't insert the object contents into the form values?

~edit~ Added form as requested.

---

**template**

```
#... snip
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_ul }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

---

**view**

```
from forms import EmployeeCreateFormAutoIDPlusInvite
class EmployeeUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Employee
    template_name = 'employee_single.html'
    form_class = EmployeeCreateFormAutoIDPlusInvite
```

---

**form**

```
class EmployeeCreateFormAutoID(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        exclude = ['user','last_updated_date','last_updated_by','date_created',
            'created_by','reports_to','company','employee_id']

class EmployeeCreateFormAutoIDPlusInvite(EmployeeCreateFormAutoID):
    """
    Extends employee creation form by adding user info for invitations.
    """
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_("First name"),
        max_length=30, required=True,
        help_text=_("Required. 30 character max length."))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_("Last name"),
        max_length=30, required=True,
        help_text=_("Required. 30 character max length."))
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"),
        help_text=_("Required for interactive employees, but if you are only adding"
            " this as a person for scheduling or invoicing, you needn't add it."))
```

Comment: can you give me your form class too ?

Comment: @bluebird7 - form has been added

Comment: so why you haven't `save` function in your `EmployeeCreateFormAutoID` class?

Comment: It doesn't need one. It's inhereting from ModelForm, but that isn't really relavent to my question. The data is available in the object, but is not populating the form as I typically expect.

Comment: i cant understand !you have done stuff like `form.first_name.value`, but you get None back did you saved your form after add any data in recording ? you must create a save function for saving the data to your database !

Comment: @bluebird7, you don't need a `save()` with `UpdateForm`. By the way, OP, did `EmployeeCreateFormAutoID` work instead of `EmployeeCreateFormAutoIDPlusInvite`?

Comment: @AshishKasturia Nope, doesn't work with the other form.  I hadn't tried it till now, so that's at least one other possibility removed.

Comment: How does your `url` look like?

Comment: http://localhost:80/employees/<some pk number>   which finds the object without issue.  The form just isn't populating.

Comment: So here's the thing: Turns out I'm just an idiot.  I was pulling a test model with no data in it.  Saved some address info to it and guess what: it works.